# IONIC using inappbrowser loadstart not working

Tags: ionic-framework, inappbrowser

IONIC using inappbrowser not working

```
var ref=   $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(url, '_self', options);        
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {  
    alert(event.url); $ionicLoading.show() 
}); 
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {  
    alert(event.url); 
    $ionicLoading.hide() 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ionicLoading.show();
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', inAppBrowserOptions);
  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event){
    $cordovaInAppBrowser.show();
    $timeout(function(){$ionicLoading.hide()},2000);
  });
```

For inAppBrowserOptions:

```
  .config(function($cordovaInAppBrowserProvider) {
    var defaultOptions = {
      location: 'yes',
      clearcache: 'no',
      hardwareback: 'yes',
      toolbar: 'no'
    };
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
      $cordovaInAppBrowserProvider.setDefaultOptions(defaultOptions)
    }, false);
  });
```

Comment: I need to show the loader while opening the external URL

Comment: is it not feasible to show the loader, till the external URL downloaded.

As current solution, open the loader however it show the blank screen while opening the external URL

Comment: If this solution is implemented as it is proposed, it gives you loading icon, while loading the browser in background and displays it immediately after $ionicLoading.hide() is called. Please check if your'e missing anything!

Comment: Thanks, I have forgot to mention the options [hidden to yes]